# Change colors and fonts only on main theme, not on childs

Tags: theme, frontend

I have a problem, and I do not know how to approach it. So, I am running a project in which we have a store divided into 2 store (b2c and b2b). B2C is the default template, and B2B inherits from it. Now a client came to us and he wants us to change a lot of elements e.g. site colors, fonts or e.g. header, but only on the b2c site, and b2b is to remain as is. Do you have any idea how to approach such a problem?

Changing variables storing colors, for example, will rather be invasive also on the b2b store. Any advice? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 cases:

1. B2B theme (the child theme) currently has a slight difference from the B2C theme (the parent theme) **AND** the B2C theme won't be changing much as the B2B theme in the future: You can swap out the theme role, ie. Change the B2B theme to the parent theme, and the B2C theme to the child theme. In this case, besides changing the config from `theme.xml`, you also have to update the `parent_id` from the `theme` database table.
2. If the above does not match: I would recommend you apply the changes (CSS, template) to the parent theme (B2C) and also **apply the original** from the parent theme to the child theme (B2B).

Assume, B2C and B2B use `@color: #ffffff` which is declared in B2C (the parent theme)
Your requirement is changing `@color` to `@color: #f0f0f0` for B2B (the child theme) only.
Implement:

- change `@color: #ffffff` to `@color: #f0f0f0` on B2C theme (the parent theme).
- declare `@color: #ffffff` on B2B theme (the child theme).